# How to debug 'unable to verify the first certificate' from electron app?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, electron

I am trying to connect to `wss://mydomain.com/ws` from electron app (render process), but:

```
events.js:177 Uncaught Error: unable to verify the first certificate
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1317)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:200)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:792)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:606)
```

I am using same code which works from plain Chrome and Firefox browsers

```
const WebSocket = require('isomorphic-ws')

const ws = new WebSocket('wss://mydomain.com/',
      [],
      {
        headers: {
          Cookie: cookie.serialize('X-Authorization', bearerToken),
        },
      },
);
```

I used https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=mydomain.com
to check certificate and it says:

```
Protocols
TLS 1.3 No
TLS 1.2 Yes
TLS 1.1 Yes
TLS 1.0 Yes
SSL 3   No
SSL 2   No
For TLS 1.3 tests, we only support RFC 8446.
```

However I can't see request in electron devtools, so can't verify tls version

Answer (score 0):

Using https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ I discovered

```
Chain issues.........Incomplete
```

So I fixed it on nginx side, before I used:

```
ssl_certificate /www/xx/certs/mydomain_com.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /www/xx/certs/live_server.key;
```

Now I did:

```
cat mydomain-com.crt mydomain-com.ca-bundle > mydomain_com.ca-bundle.crt
```

And changed in nginx:

```
ssl_certificate /www/xx/certs/mydomain_com.ca-bundle.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /www/xx/certs/live_server.key;
```